# Organization of Locale Files in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, locale, i18n-gem, load-path

I currently have the following 4 files in my **config/locales** of my root application:

```
-en.yml
-de.yml
-simple_form.en.yml
-simple_form.de.yml
```

In my **application.rb** which resides in a **spec/dummy** folder for testing the application gem I have the following line of code which seems to be retrieving the translations as expected:

```
# The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
config.i18n.default_locale = :de
```

I now wish to introduce to structure to the file structure of my locales folder but when I add the additional folders and change the load path in the **application.rb** I am getting translation not found errors. Here is my attempt:

Attempt at including structure in **config/locales** of my root application:

```
-views
  -en.yml
  -de.yml
-models
  -en.yml
  -de.yml
-forms
  -simple_form.en.yml
  -simple_form.de.yml
```

And my load path in the **application.rb** changed to:

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
```

According to the following rails guide:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-domain-name

Comment: Please show us the specific error you are getting. Do you have a stack trace you can share?

Comment: In the view I am receiving the string: translation missing: en.new_tenant.header, I an not seeing any error messages

Comment: Could the problem be that the application.rb file resides in a spec folder for testing purposes and that my config folder is not being loaded at the root level and I am only seeing the translations as the config/locales are added automatically but not any subfolders?

Comment: Dir[Rails.root.to_s] results in the string C:/Sites/MyApp/spec/dummy which is the dummy app for testing MyApp. The config folder with the translations resides at C:/Sites/MyApp/Config/Locales/

Comment: I tried the tried this: my_root = "C:/Sites/MyApp"
 config.i18n.load_path += Dir[my_root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    config.i18n.default_locale = :de

Comment: But the join method is unrecognised for this string

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To test the host application you need to change the i18n.load_path to the config folder of your main app and not the dummy spec for testing purposes. Code as follows:

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
```

Comment: For me the string was: `config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
`

Comment: Better use `Rails.root` than an hard coded root path

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue, I solved it by adding this line to my application.rb config:

```
# load the subfolders in the locales
config.i18n.load_path += Dir["#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/locales/**/*.{rb,yml}"]
```

Answer (score 3):

The following options all worked for me

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir["#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/locales/**/*.yml"]

config.i18n.load_path += Dir["#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/locales/**/*.{rb,yml}"]

config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**' '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
```

After **restarting** the webserver of course...

Answer (score 2):

Want to mention. All solutions above also include files in `config/locales` directory again (first time rails add it by itself). It's not a problem becase values will be rewritten with the same keys. But if you want to include ONLY subdirectory files inside `config/locales` it is better to use
`config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]`

Example.
My structure:

```
config/
  locales/
    en.yml
    breadcrumbs/
      breadcrumbs.en.yml
```

If you do `config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]` you add en.yml several times:

```
irb(main):001:0> Rails.application.config.i18n.load_path
=> ["/home/air/projects/qq2/config/locales/en.yml"]
irb(main):002:0> Rails.application.config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
irb(main):003:0> Rails.application.config.i18n.load_path
=> ["/home/air/projects/qq2/config/locales/en.yml", "/home/air/projects/qq2/config/locales/en.yml", "/home/air/projects/qq2/config/locales/breadcrumbs/breadcrumbs.en.yml"]
```

with `Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]`:

```
irb(main):001:0> Rails.application.config.i18n.load_path
=> ["/home/air/projects/qq2/config/locales/en.yml"]
irb(main):002:0> Rails.application.config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
irb(main):003:0> Rails.application.config.i18n.load_path
=> ["/home/air/projects/qq2/config/locales/en.yml", "/home/air/projects/qq2/config/locales/breadcrumbs/breadcrumbs.en.yml"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In `config/application.rb`:

```
module PointsProject
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
  end
end
```

From Rails's guide on Internationalization: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-domain-name