# Rails Internationalization: i18n look up with nested locales directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, i18n-gem

I am trying to organize my localization files with a nested file structure so that it is easier to look up.

I have followed

[Organization of Locale Files in rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735882/organization-of-locale-files-in-rails-app)

[How do you structure i18n yaml files in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282857/how-do-you-structure-i18n-yaml-files-in-rails)

but I am getting a translation missing: `en.view.fruits.apple`. I think that Rails is trying to only look up the translation in `locales/en.yml` file but not the sub-directories although, I have included them.

config/application.rb:

```
 config.i18n.load_path += Dir["#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/locales/**/*.{rb,yml}"]
```

My locales directory:

```
|locales   
|-en.yml
|-views
|--en.yml
```

locales/views/en.yml:

```
en:
  fruits:
    apple: "apple"
```

views/fruit.html.haml:

```
= I18n.t('views.fruits.apple')
```

Comment: you need to scope the keys in your files!

Comment: You can use lazy lookup with your own custom scope: https://github.com/abitdodgy/i18n_lazy_scope

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem solved

in my views/fruit.html.haml

instead of

```
= I18n.t('views.fruits.apple')
```

it should be

```
= I18n.t('fruits.apple')
```

since all the sub-folders are preload from

config/application.rb

```
 config.i18n.load_path += Dir["#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/locales/**/*.{rb,yml}"]
```

And don't forget you need to restart your server !!

Comment: An alternative would have been to nest everything under 'views' in the yml file, so that is  basically:   {en: views: fruits: apple: "apple"}. Rails doesn't interpret the scopes based on files locations/names, only on the content of the yml.